# Where is the package sources location

Tags: visual-studio

I use VS 2015 .Where in the visual studio project store the setting of  Tools>options >Nuget Package Manager >Package Sources's setting. Currently Nuget.org is checked for Package Sources.I want to point this to a different location other than https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/, by editing the file location.
I checked the project file csproj, but did not find it
I need to change this manually in the server to point to the server repository. Working fine in local machine but not in the server.

Comment: I can't think of anything edited via Tools -> Options that *would* be reflected in a csproj, since they're "global" options, not per-project options.

Answer (score 10):

This is a per-user setting, and is stored in `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`. The file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Abc" value="http://def/nuget/" />
    <add key="Package source" value="http://packagesource" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
</configuration>
```

Simply add another entry into the `<packageSources>` element. (Mine is obviously updated for the protocol version 3 and so is referencing `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` rather than `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/`).